# Is there a way to put a probability threshold on beam search when using hugginface transformer?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am using a huggingface model of type `transformers.modeling_gpt2.GPT2LMHeadModel` and using beam search to predict the text.

- Is there any way to get the probability calculated in beam search for returned sequence.
- Can I put a condition to return a text sequence only when it crosses some threshold probability.

Below code gives the 5 texts' tokens but I need the probability of those 5 sequences.

````
test_beam_outputs = model.generate(
    test_input_ids,
    max_length=len(test_text.split(' ')) + 20,
    num_beams=5,
    early_stopping=True,
    
    length_penalty=0.5,
    num_return_sequences=5,
    no_repeat_ngram_size=2
)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but here is this. This, however, only works to predict the next word.

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Load model and tokenizer
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Input example
input_txt = "I like to"
inputs = tokenizer(input_txt, return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**inputs)

# If you are not on a source install, replace outputs[0] by outputs.logits 
predictions = F.softmax(outputs[0], dim=-1)

thresh = 0.001
vocab_size = predictions.shape[-1]

idxs = torch.arange(0, vocab_size)[predictions[0][-1] >= thresh]
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(idxs))
```

---

Courtsey of: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/print-all-tokens-over-a-certain-probability-threshold/329/2

Comment: I think this is for next word probability but I want to put a probability threshold on beam search. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @DivyanshuShekhar You're right. I'm not sure how to do that.